# UITextField in UITableView cell behaving strangely with shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am using custom delegation with my UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell.  Basically I have UITextFields on my UITableView, and in Edit mode, I want to be able to edit the content inside the UITextField.

My issue is that when I go into Edit mode and try to type something in the text field, I am only able to type one character and it doubles.  In this example, I tried to type "p" and it only lets me type "p" and it changes to "pp".
[image]

Here's my code.  As an FYI I am pretty new to iOS/programming/custom delegation/custom UITableViewCells.

UITableViewCell subclass .h:

```
@protocol MenuTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)updatedFoodItem:(NSString *)foodItem fromCell:(id)sender;

@end

@interface MenuTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MenuTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *foodTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *priceTextField;

@end
```

UITableViewCell .m:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.foodTextField.delegate = self;
}
// Delegate method for tableview cell - food item text field is within cell.
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.delegate updatedFoodItem:string fromCell:self];
    return YES;
}
```

In my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)updatedFoodItem:(NSString *)foodItem fromCell:(MenuTableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *p = [self.menuTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    id item = self.menuItemsArray[p.row];
    cell.foodTextField.text = foodItem;
}
```

By the way I realize that the above probably isn't updating my data yet, I haven't figured it out yet so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling your `updatedFoodItem:` method **and then** returning `YES` in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` function. Essentially what's happening is:

1 - `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` is called

2 - This function calls `updatedFoodItem:`

3 - The `updatedFoodItem:` function sets the `cell`'s text field to the original text passed in

4 - The `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method returns `YES`, appending the same text that was just set in the `updatedFoodItem:` function to the cell's label

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do (maybe you're trying to save the food item into your `self.menuItemsArray`?), but you should either not set the cell's text in the `updatedFoodItem:` function, or you should return `NO` in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` function.